# PHP Facebook Graph API: How to post a Photo on Facebook's Custom App's Photo Album

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to make an App on Facebook. From that app the user should to able to upload a Photo or comment to the app's album.
I did the comment part, So the user is able to post a comment from the app to the app's wall.

But I am not able to POST a photo to the apps photo album. When ever I upload any picture it goes to the user wall.

The below code is what im using.

```
$fb = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => '2420527xxxxxxx',
'secret' => 'a6b14d618xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
));

$graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/".$fb->getAppId()."/photos?access_token=".$fb->getAccessToken();        

echo "
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="'.$graph_url.'" method="post">
    <input name="source" type="file" /><br/>
    <input name="message" type="text" value="" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
 </form>
 ";
```

Have anybody here done that before..? Any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 0):

The photo isn't going to their wall, it's actually going to a new album in their profile that has been created for your app. Look at their photo albums and you should see it there. Facebook does a little bit of unspecified magic with posting something to their wall when new photos are uploaded to an album.

If you would rather that the photo go to a specific album, then you will need to specify the album id that the photo should go to.

```
// first get your album id, let's assume you need to create it
// create this before hand and you can just reference the id
$attachment = array('access_token'=> ACCESS_TOKEN, 'name'=>$ablum_name);
try{
    $album_resp = $facebook->api("/{$this->page_id}/albums", 'POST', $attachment);
}catch(Exception $e){
    throw new Exception("Failed to create album: ". $e->getMessage());
}
$album_id = $album_resp['id'];

$graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/". $album_id ."/photos?access_token=".$fb->getAccessToken();

// continue with your posting...
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for your reply, I am able to POST on the user's profile in an album with the app's name.   What I wanted was the album/photo instead of going in the users profile it should go in the photo section of the app...so it is visible to all the FANS of that app...  Do you follow what am I trying to do..?

Comment: Yea, I see what you are saying. Have you tried using the id of an album that you created for the app?